# Looking for a way to secure round rods in a T configuration

Tags: repair, hardware

[image]

Looking for a good way to tightly connect two round rods in a T configuration.

I figured something like a T-clamp would be the obvious solution and easy to buy, but I have searched **rather extensively** and the closest thing I've found online is [This](https://www.qcsupply.com/410550-free-stall-parlor-repair-parts-1-5-8-1-5-8-3-bolt-t-clamp.html), and from the measurements quoted it appears way too big.

In my application the vertical part is a 3/8" diameter steel rod, and the horizontal crossbar is a 7/8" diameter wood handle (to twist the rod). The rod is already inserted into a hole in the handle, but after many years the handle is now slipping, hence the need for a fix.

Can anyone suggest a reasonably simple means to secure the handle so it won't slip? I know I've seen T-clamps in pictures somewhere, but if they aren't as commonly available as I thought, I may need something different.

*The local Home Depot has told me on the phone that they don't have anything like this.*

Thanks.

Comment: How muck torque is involved with the turning?

Comment: A photo of the thing you are trying to repair may shed light or stimulate an alternative fix.

Comment: The specs on the product you linked to say 1 5/8" X 1 5/8" so that would be for a  1 5/8" pipe or handle, a little larger but not smaller. NO?

Comment: I wasn't sure. I thought the 1 5/8" was the length/width of the product. Actually it didn't "look" that big in the photo (to me), but later, I realized it could be the intended diameter. Anyway if that's the case, it definitely won't work for me.

Comment: The mechanism turns a valve on & off for our lawn sprinkler system. So the torque to shut it off is similar to the force needed to turn off an outdoor water faucet, although it's actually somewhat harder to turn than a faucet. Right now I am turning it on & off by attaching two vise-grips, very tightly, to the vertical rod, and using them as handles.

Comment: why don't you bend the rod into L shape?

Comment: I added a photo, but the junction is obscured by some duct tape I applied to see if it would help. It helps some, but is too flimsy to last long.

Comment: The rod is too thick for me to bend. This would also make the user stoop down to turn it, and the leverage would be reduced because you couldn't use both hands in the same way you can now.

Comment: Consider replacing the current handle with a "kerb key" (or "curb key"). These are used to turn the water on/off at the meter, but may be suitable/adaptable for your use.

Comment: I actually have a key as you describe for turning the water meter on & off, but it's much thicker and heavier than this handle, and the attachment at the bottom is completely different. In fact I doubt I could even remove the current handle without a lot more effort than it would take to fix it another way.

Comment: you could weld on a piece of metal bar. Epoxy -might- work, if only for a while

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to find an appropriate clamp, but this appears to just be an irrigation shut-off key.
They are not expensive brand new and I'd bet that the whole new key doesn't cost more than whatever speciality clamp you might ultimately find

Comment: This is not a standard handle. It was put together from scratch by the previous owner of the house.

Comment: Ok @Warren but the valve surely is like other valves, right? So handles built to activate valves might work